# How to prevent node creation if blacklisted words detected in the body?

Tags: 7

I have a forum and when user creates new thread (which is some custom content type) and if the thread lets say has word 'loan' in it somewhere, in a title field, or a body field and etc. then the thread doesn't get saved and gives some warning or something like that.

Is there a module for that? Recently my forum got spammed with loans and there's about 1000 of those threads and all about loans. And those spams bypass all anti spam protections. So I came up with this 'brilliant' idea.

Please don't suggest Captchas and etc. I need something like I described with a blacklist.

Comment: Tomorrow he/she may start spamming about insurance ! Do you have any captcha in forms ? I know some bots can break captcha as well, adding this should be first thing to do I think.

Comment: I have lots of modules set, Capthas, Mollom, AntiSpam with Akismet, HoneyPot. And after month of monitoring the spam all I get is 'loan' spam in my forums and nothing else.

Comment: Your problem is probably not with bots but with actual human spammers. It's necessary to be a bit more devious to deal with those. You can probably do what you describe with Rules. Rules will also help if you want to implement some sort of reputation-based system to reduce spam.

Comment: I think @AlfredArmstrong is right, it sounds like humans (ie, a meatnet).  These can be very hard to deal with (several SE sites, including Drupal Answers are currently having problems).

Comment: The problem with a blacklist system is that it cannot make a contextual decision. For instance 'payday loan' and 'on loan from the museum' have very different meanings. The latter might be a valid post. Rather than blocking creation, you might consider putting the post in moderation and informing the user a possible problem has been detected and the post will be reviewed. If I spent a chunk of time carefully wording a post only to have it evaporate into thin air, I would be unlikely to risk a repeat. You should also look at the [Spambot](http://drupal.org/project/spambot) module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give you working code, but the basic approach I have used is:

- Make a new Vocabulary.  Call it Naughty Words.  Populate it with all of your naughty words.
- [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) your submission form, and push on a new `$form['#validate']` functions.
- In your validation function, read in all of the naughty word terms into an array.  Then check the submitted element(s) against the naughty words.  [`form_set_error()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) if there is a match.

There are several ways to do the matching.  One is a simple loop with a strpos against each term; another is to explode the submission and then do an array intersection.  Play around with it in something standalone.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Recaptcha](http://drupal.org/project/recaptcha) with captcha. I did not get a single spam submission since the time I've installed this module :-)

> Uses the [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha) web service to improve the CAPTCHA system and protect email addresses.

It uses Google's web service for authenticating, which is pretty much secure.

Answer (score 0):

There are many modules available in drupal for such spam prevention.

I suggest [Mollom](http://drupal.org/project/mollom) module

> Mollom is an "intelligent" content moderation web service. By
>   monitoring content activity on all sites in the Mollom network, Mollom
>   is in a unique position to determine if a post is potentially spam;
>   not only based on the posted content, but also on the past activity
>   and reputation of the poster. In short, Mollom handles incoming posts
>   intelligently, in much the same way a human moderator decides what
>   posts are acceptable.

Comment: I have tried it and many spams still gets passed.

Answer (score 0):

Alter that node_add_form and add additional validation function